# Recommended size of data returned by EJB API call

Tags: performance, ejb

does anyone know if there is any limitation for the size of data that can be obtained in the output of EJB API call?

Let's say output to API should be an array of some complex objects. How long array can go?

We are planning to use pagination for retrieving data by portions and want to determine the ideal size of portion/bulk

Answer (score 1):

> does anyone know if there is any limitation for the size of data that can be obtained in the output of EJB API call?

To my knowledge, there is no hard limit on the size of the object returned in an RMI call. In practice, you might be limited by memory resources... and "time" (e.g. a transaction timeout) but this shouldn't happen if you're not doing insane things.

> Let's say output to API should be an array of some complex objects. How long array can go?

Even if the answer to the previous question had been "X", I hope you realize it would still have been impossible to answer this one.

> We are planning to use pagination for retrieving data by portions and want to determine the ideal size of portion/bulk

IMO, this is more a usability issue than a technical issue so I suggest to discuss it with your usability expert.

Comment: Right, it's mostly memory based.  Also note that not all EJB implementations use RMI, some have proprietary protocols and that protocol may already have some form of chunked encoding (either based on HTTP or similar).  Definitely follow @Boris' advice and ask you vendor first.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to the customer/product owner/project placeholder and ask for their expectations. Write test automating the specification. Tweak the code until the tests are met.